# c# socket send data mismatch server data

Tags: c#, tcpclient

while sending byte[] data via socket (a/sync) i'm getting on messagereceived event mismatch data. For example like this

client:

```
2013-05-20 12:03:09.6929|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:09.8619|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:10.0249|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:10.1899|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:10.3459|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:10.5220|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:10.6890|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:10.8630|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:11.0490|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:11.2040|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:11.3680|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:11.5340|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:11.7030|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:11.8600|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
2013-05-20 12:03:12.0340|DEBUG|Tcp|SendAsync_Completed: Sent ( ; T A , 59 84 65 13 10  ) to 127.0.0.1:10002 (Table)!
```

server:

```
2013-05-20 12:03:09.6819|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:09.8959|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A ; T
2013-05-20 12:03:10.0799|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = A ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:10.2569|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:10.4750|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:10.6600|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:10.8830|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A ; T
2013-05-20 12:03:11.0790|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = A ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:11.2700|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:11.5090|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:11.7120|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A ; T
2013-05-20 12:03:11.9180|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = A ; T A
2013-05-20 12:03:12.1000|DEBUG|Table|TableServer.Cmd = ; T A
```

I have tried everything. Switching from async to sync send, thread sleep before send, but nothing works...

Comment: Can we see your receive code? I suspect I know exactly what the problem is... 9 times out of 10 it relates to how people handle the return value of `Read` / `Receive`

Comment: I don't know :). The server is a table itself (its a device with wi fi ), so he is getting lags when the packets are mismatched...Stupid imo

Comment: if there are "lags", then check whether the sender has the "NODELAY" flag set at their end. Lag can be introduced by routing problems, but can also be caused by the sender's NIC buffering (again emphasizing: how you call "send" can be very unrelated to the composition of what actually gets sent)

Comment: Ok, but i can only set wi fi settings like in printer with wifi/adhoc.

Comment: the "NODELAY" flag is a core part of the send code. Either the sender is including NODELY, or they aren't. You can't tweak that at the adapter level: it must be the calling code.

Comment: Yes. But you have to understand that this table is stupid somehow. I meant he is getting lag when the received bytes are in random order and it cant do anything with that...

Comment: the data you have shown does not illustrate "random order". The bytes are in the original order, from what I can see. "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC" is exactly the same *when treated as a stream*, as "A", "BCA", "B", "CABCA", "B", "C". The both represent "ABCABCABCABC". Any particular "gaps", "groups" and "spacing" only exist in our imagination.

Comment: Ok, now i get it :). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [http://tiny.cc/io](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html), in particular the "Network packets: what you send is not (usually) what you get". It looks like you are expecting to write as per:

```
var blob = new byte[] {59,84,65,13,10};
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    network.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
```

and then *have it read* as 10 blocks of 5. However, that simply doesn't work: TCP is a stream. When you call `Read`, you will get "some data, at least one byte or EOF, and at most {count} bytes". The protocol does know not and *cannot* know how the send code was structured. It could have been buffered at sourse, or not. Packets could be combined and split. All that is guaranteed is that you get the same bytes, in the same order. But not necessarily in the same chunks.

So basically: it is *your job* to separate the messages. In this case, it looks like you could do that by reading to the sentinel value of `13`,`10`. At the most basic level, that could be something like:

```
    byte[] ReadToNewline()
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        int val;
        do
        {
            val = netStream.ReadByte();
            if (val < 0) throw EOF();
            if (val == '\r')
            {
                val = netStream.ReadByte();
                if (val == '\n') return ms.ToArray();
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected end-of-line");
            }
            ms.WriteByte((byte)val);
        } while (true);
    }
```

More elegant solutions are possible; I simply took that from [SimpleRedis](https://code.google.com/p/simple-redis/source/browse/SimpleRedis/RedisClient.cs). You might prefer to read larger buffers locally and just loop through the received buffer looking for the CR/LF pair - noting that the CR could be at the end of one "read", with the LF at the start of another, etc.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I just want to make sure :)

Comment: @luk4 note that the code above *excludes* the sentinel values; if you want the `13` / `10` included, then obviously just add them

Comment: Yea, it doesnt matter. The server is a device so I cant even fix that. Btw there is a colleration betweeen how fast data is sent over socket and how many misplaced data is received...

Comment: @luk4 define "misplaced". I don't see any misplaced data in your sample. That looks like perfectly normal TCP traffic to me. Again: all that is guaranteed is that you get the same bytes in the same order. The composition of the chunks is undefined.

Comment: I meant - the same order of bytes. If I send very fast data via socket i will get this situation often than if i send it slower. Is it correct?

Comment: @luk4 the "situation" in the information in the question is "business as usual; TCP working correctly". I cannot comment much more because *you haven't shown how you are using it*. As as I commented earlier, the "NODELAY" flag could be a factor here. But fundamentally: what the receiver is receiving is entirely correct and normal: they need to write code that correctly treats the data as a stream. I would expect that it remains correct and normal for both fast and slow networks.

Comment: Yup, i have already set no delay for send's socket. I understand that TCP works like that, but tests showed me that faster sending data will case much more mismatched data. Which is correct as You said. Thanks for answers and help :)

Comment: @luk4 and again I say: *there is no mismatched data*. Any appearance of mismatched-ness is entirely the fault of incorrect reading code.